# Как сделать календарь бронирования на js html css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Всем привет! Не могу как сделать календарь как на фото, чтобы были зеленые поля(свободные даты) и красные поля(забронированные даты). Бронироваться(краситься в красный) будет при нажатии на дату.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: :))) Вопрос можно отредактировать кнопкой [**править**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1472449/edit).

Comment: Ну тут скорее всего идёт переключения класса, можно попробовать через `element.classList.toggle` менять класс который будет менять цвет на красный / зелёный.

Answer (score 1):

Вы разметки не дали так что пришлось импровизировать :)

##### JS

Сначала объявил переменные, сам календарь и дни недель (на английском).

```js
let $calendar = document.querySelector('#calendar')
let days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
```

Дальше за каждый день недели создал новый столб с первой буквой дня (каждой дал класс `name`).

```js
days.forEach(e => {
  let day = document.createElement('div')

  day.textContent = e[0]
  day.className = 'name'
  $calendar.appendChild(day)
})
```

Дальше через цикл создал сами дни недель, там думаю объяснять не стоит, весь код спокойно читается (Если хотите, напишите в комментариях и я вам объясню).

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 36; i++) {
  let day = document.createElement('div')
  let dayNum = i - 5
  let isEmpty = dayNum < 1

  day.className = 'block' + (isEmpty ? ' empty' : '')
  day.textContent = isEmpty ? '' : dayNum
  $calendar.appendChild(day)
}
```

Дальше используя метод делегации событий повесил событие на сам календарь, и если пользователь нажимал на ячейку у которой из классов только `block`, то тогда к блоку добавляется класс `active` (Соответственно к блоку будет добавляться класс `active` только тогда, когда блок не пустой и не активный).

```js
$calendar.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if(e.target.matches('[class="block"]')) {
    e.target.classList.add('active')
  }
})
```

##### CSS

Добавил стандартные стили и ещё более красивый шрифт.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, 'Segoe UI';
}
```

Дальше через grid сделал 7 колонн (т.к. 7 дней недели).

```css
#calendar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, auto);
}
```

Сделал высоту 50 пикселей (3.125em == 50px) и немного разделил блоки, также сделал так, чтобы текст был в центре блока и его нельзя было бы выделить.

```css
.block {
  height: 3.125em;
  margin: .125em;
  display: grid;
  background-color: rgb(221, 255, 204);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

Ну и дальше самые простые CSS стили которые даже не нуждаются в объяснении

```css
.name, .block {
  text-align: center;
}

.name {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.empty {
  background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
}

.active {
  background-color: rgb(255, 192, 189);
}
```

Вот тут вся HTML разметка :)

```html
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: Само понятие бронирования напрашивает, чтобы результат сохранить на сервачке. (чтобы другие могли посмотреть)

Comment: @Опан где же я вам сервер достану :)? Я думал что это что-то типа формы которая отправляется на сервер.

Comment: Откровенно говоря, так и не понял, о чём Вы. (видать, я сегодня ещё не употребил 150 грамм.)

Comment: Ну смотрите, дизайн у календаря не особо современный, скорее всего работает на чём-то старом, может PHP и беря этот факт, я и подумал что это какая-то форма со своим JS'ом и соответственно отправка идёт на сервер где уже и будет происходить магия проверки на свободные места (ну и логично будет просто потом показывать какие места не свободны).

Answer (score 0):

Я бы конечно подошёл с другого конца. Раз вопрос о бронировании, то нужно хранить об этом инфу и считывать постоянно актуальную, т.е. в момент нажатия проверять не занят ли день, соответственно логика такая:
кликаем->получаем id элемента и его значение -> отправляем на сервак аяксом и смотрим не занят ли день другим пользователем(логику проверки пользователя нет смысла описывать), далее закрепляем бронь за текущим пользователем и возвращаем ответ в виде перекраски бэеграунда элемента или полной его перерисовке.
P.S. Если же вам без логики, просто менять цвет дива, то вам при добавлении элемента, всё ровно необходимо присваивать уникальный id с нарастающим значением, например 'id_'+i, далее вешать обработчик на клик по диву и вылавливать его функцией, которая будет уже заниматься всеми манипуляциями с элементом.